# Swift 5 | How to pass additional parameters to selector @objc

Tags: uibutton, swift5

How can I pass additional parameters to a selector @objc function in Swift 5?

What I would like to do is this:

```
    @objc func sendLike(_ sender: Any, checkin: String) {
    
    createLikeCheckin(checkin: checkin) // This is the URLSession function
}

// In tableView cellForRowAt
let checkin = self.userCheckins[indexPath.row]
cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendLike(_:, checkin: checkin.pk)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

So I can pass the checkin object's pk to then use in a URLSession. However I get the error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call Insert '<#Any#>, '

which leads me to this error after selecting fix: Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

Comment: You can't do that. Partial application of a function is not a selector. You might want to have a look at how to turn a closure into a selector, e.g. https://gist.github.com/cprovatas/98ff940140c8744c4d1f3bcce7ba4543

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot add target with parameters in CollectionViewCell's button (Swift 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211252/cannot-add-target-with-parameters-in-collectionviewcells-button-swift-4)

Comment: Those are both helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm just horrible at searching

Answer: [Pass multiple parameters to addTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498064/pass-multiple-parameters-to-addtarget/39584022#39584022)

Some other references: [Attach parameter to button.addTarget action in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814646/attach-parameter-to-button-addtarget-action-in-swift)